# Upgrading to SSD: Is it OK to just transfer everything?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I'm running windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010 on a standard HDD. The SSD I bought comes with a transfer kit that makes it easy to just transfer everything over to the new drive? Are there any reasons not to do this?

Comment: Vote Move to Super User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine, just make sure you disable indexing, hibernation, and enable trim:

http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?63273-*-Windows-7-Ultimate-Tweaks-amp-Utilities-*

Answer (score 1):

Ah. No. Really. If it fits... and you keep the original disc to fall back, just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your machine isn't constantly writing, otherwise sit back and enjoy the speed :)

Answer (score 0):

The SSD should appear to BIOS and Windows as a standard IDE/SATA drive, so, in theory, no.  It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your transfer kit only copies files the ssd may not be bootable without doing a "startup repair".

Another option would be to use the built in Windows Backup to do a full image backup of your existing drive, replace the drive with the SSD and then restore from your image backup.  This has worked well for me in the past, and the additional backup provides another level of safety.

Windows 7 should disable defrag, and enable trim automatically.

Cheers!
JE

Answer (score -1):

I found it helpful to re-install the OS fresh, this time making use of a separate pair of 'Program Files' & 'Program Files (x64)' folders on the slow(er) drive for the apps that don't need help to load quickly.

I save the SSD for slow apps like Office & Adobe that do benefit from the SSD.

Some apps use environment variables differently than others, and had to be re-installed to the actual system-defined 'Program Files' directory, but most who offer the choice to change the installation path respect that decision.